# Spring Boot Admin - info.version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

We have a service which uses a custom context path. In order to correctly register our Service on Eureka Server, we've set the following:

```
eureka.instance.statusPageUrl=http://xxx/custom/info
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrl=http://xxx/custom/health
eureka.instance.homePageUrl=http://xxx/custom/
```

This is working well, our application gets registered. However, although we have set the `info.version` information, it doesn't get displayed on the `Spring Boot Admin` homepage. For our application where we don't have a custom context path, it's working:

[image]

Any idea which property(ies) is/are eventually missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following into your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[Documentation link](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.2/#show-version-in-application-list)